# Tracing request origin on Elastic Cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-cloud

I have an old Elasticsearch cluster that shouldn't be getting traffic but somehow it still is. I have hundreds of services that could potentially be hitting it. I'm looking for a way to maybe capture the request origin so I can see where the requests are coming from. I tried enabling the REST request tracer but that didn't seem to do anything (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you have authentication enabled (or are ok to enable it and let requests fail then), I would enable [audit logging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enable-audit-logging.html). This will log auditing events including an `origin.address`, which should show you where those are coming from.

Example (request on localhost):

```
{
  "type": "audit",
  "timestamp": "2020-07-29T20:11:08,529+0200",
  "node.id": "sDCzapQcSgCTgaOnebA07w",
  "event.type": "rest",
  "event.action": "anonymous_access_denied",
  "origin.type": "rest",
  "origin.address": "127.0.0.1:58611",
  "url.path": "/",
  "request.method": "HEAD",
  "request.id": "4s_UWL35TfiI0nGZvNeomA"
}
```

Though on Elastic Cloud you will have to contact support to provide you those logs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Sounds like it could work but I'm currently running into an error that reads 

`Logging settings can only be specified if the cluster has a target deployment set for log delivery.`

Once I figure that out I'l let you know if it works. Or if you have any guidance that's appreciated as well!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I thought the log delivery cluster would be currently a private beta feature at the moment. It should be available soon-ish, but support might be able to help you in the meantime.